# Let variable assinged inside Promise constructor is being marked as undefined by Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am defining a `let` variable called `resolver` which then I want to assign inside a promise constructor function.

```
interface Request {
    ids: string[];
    resolver: () => void;
    promise: Promise<unknown>
}

class Foo {
    public requests: Request[] = [];

    public createPromise = (ids: string[]) => {
        let resolver;

        const promise = new Promise((r) => { resolver = r; });

        this.requests.push({ ids, resolver, promise });

        return promise;
    };
}
```

But I'm getting the following TypeScript error for the `resolver` when I try to push the object to the requests list:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
```

The `resolver` variable I am assigning inside the promise constructor is being marked as `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that need to be changed.

- The local `resolver` variable should be given an explicit type that matches that of the request interface.
- You need to assert (`!`) that the variable will be assigned. The assignment happens in a callback function and TS has not way to know when this function will be called. A different class might take a similar callback in the constructor and not call it immediately.
- The function in the request interface should take a value argument of a matching type to the promise. If you do not need a resolved value, you can use `Promise<void>` instead.

```
interface IRequest {
    ids: string[];
    resolver: (value: unknown) => void;
    promise: Promise<unknown>
}

class Foo {
    public requests: IRequest[] = [];

    public createPromise = (ids: string[]) => {
        let resolver!: (value: unknown) => void;

        const promise = new Promise((r) => { resolver = r; });

        this.requests.push({ ids, resolver, promise });

        return promise;
    };
}
```

(Renamed interface to not conflict with `fetch` API `Request`.)

---

Example of the assignment issue:

```js
class FakePromise {
  constructor(executor) {
    // *crickets*
  }
}

let resolver1;
new Promise(r => resolver1 = r);
console.log(resolver1); // function () ...

let resolver2;
new FakePromise(r => resolver2 = r);
console.log(resolver2); // undefined
```