# Typescript error on assignment inside Promise constructor (related to executor callback?)

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

Here is a (hopefully minimal) example of what I first did:

```
  let resolveIt: CallableFunction;
  const dispatchPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolveIt = () => {resolve(true)};
  });
  resolveIt();
```

typescript (perhaps rightly so) gives me the following error on 'resolveIt();':

`Variable 'resolveIt' is used before being assigned.`

My question is, is it *really* not defined immediately? (inside the Promise constructor?)

My main confusion came about when I did a test to see if calling it *immediately* would cause it to execute the *first* initial assignment (the empty function `() => {}`) or if it would in fact execute the assigned function that prints out `TEST` to the console:

```
  let resolveIt: CallableFunction = () => {};
  const dispatchPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolveIt = () => {console.log('TEST'); resolve(true)};
  });
  resolveIt();
```

Here it actually printed out `TEST` so I was caught off guard by this. If I can't access the initial function at all after running a block of code that re-assigns the function variable, should it not then be type safe to assume that it will always be assigned? (the call is as close to the assignment as it can be right?).

My thoughts (although scattered) are that this might be some sort of "immediately invoked async code" it appears to be immediate, but perhaps there is no real guarantee that it is? (and therefore TS warns me about this?)

---

I've seen the Q/A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472963/let-variable-assinged-inside-promise-constructor-is-being-marked-as-undefined-by) and it still leaves me wondering *why* this happens?

Comment: Your question is answered by jcalz [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385552/object-is-possibly-undefined-in-typescript). I am well aware that the problem is different, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question (no anticipatory follow-up questions), or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Comment: The promise executor function (what you pass to `new Promise()`) is always called synchronously so you can rely on the fact that it will execute immediately.

Comment: TypeScript just doesn't know to handle callbacks to `new Promise` any different than callbacks pass to arbitrary functions - which may execute the callback once, never, multiple, or in the future; you can't know unless you read the documentation/specification of the called function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from my issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42910 this is an established weakness of Typescript's support for Promise control flow.

It IS safe to assume that the value has been assigned and it is a common workaround `to force the issue with a !` to indicate that it is known to have been assigned.

The example from the issue reads like this with the assertion and first line of the initialiser being 'atomic' - in other words nothing can happen to prevent myfun being set...

```js
let myfun!:() => void;
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    myfun = () => {
        doTidyUp();
        resolve;
    }
})
```